# Powershell MessageBox adding unwanted data to my variable

Tags: powershell

Consider this Powershell code:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”)

Function MyFunction {
    ShowMessageBox "Hello World" "Test"
    return "Somevalue"
}

Function ShowMessageBox {
    param (
        [string] $message,
        [string] $title
    )
    [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$message", "$title", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
    return $null
}


$variable = MyFunction
Write-Host "The value of my variable is: $variable."
```

I assign the variable, $variable, whichever is returned by the function "MyFunction", which is the string "Somevalue".

Before returning this string, I show a message box.

Then I print the value of $variable. This should be "Somevalue", but I get this as a result instead:

> OK Somevalue

Where is this extra "OK " coming from?

Comment: Your function is outputting results from `[MessageBox]::Show` and then a `$null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell everything that you don't assign or pipe to a cmdlet gets put to the pipeline. The return statement only exits a function, In your case you can omit it.

To fix your issue, pipe the result of the `Show` method to `Out-Null`:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”)

Function MyFunction {
    ShowMessageBox "Hello World" "Test"
    "Somevalue"
}

Function ShowMessageBox {
    param (
        [string] $message,
        [string] $title
    )
    [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$message", "$title", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information) | Out-Null
}


$variable = MyFunction
Write-Host "The value of my variable is: $variable."
```

Comment: Interesting to know. I never had any issues with this until this particular case. Thanks.